# Xamarin Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, xaml-designer

I'm trying to learn how to use xamarin in VS 17 to create an android app, but i can't seem to add more than one control to the xaml design page, help thank u in advance.

Comment: `ContentPage` can only have one child. Try adding any `Layout` first and children inside it

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills i don't know what by all that and what I'm saying in there isn't anything there just a single text view and i can't add another control

Comment: @Shan how would i go about doing that?

Comment: Use a Layout - a StackLayout, Grid, etc - to act as a container for multiple child controls.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/layouts

Comment: @Katleho - Which project are you working on Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.android? Are you doing drag & drop from toolbox?

Comment: thank you i was able to figure it out i change layout to linear